# How to run another copy of python 3

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pygame

I have tow copies of python 3 on my mac (running macOS Sierra, Mid 2012) one with pygame installed and one without.

If I try to run my game script I get an error message that there is **no module named pygame**

I use sublime text to edit my python files and want the terminal open to just hit the **up arrow** and **Enter** to run my scrip after I edited it.

Comment: Not sure what your question really is. Why do you have 2 Pythons - why not just one that works? If you need 2 for some unexplained reason, why not just install *”pygame”* on the other? Or use the one with *”pygame”*?

Comment: I can't install another pygame (the way pip works) but I can't run the script with the python with pygame on.Is there a way to run the python with pygame downloaded in it through terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual environments are a good practice in python development. Install virtualenv.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Create new virtual environment then activate it and install all required packages. This approach will allow you to have specific packages for each project you're working on.

More about virtual environments [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)